# App rejected - iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, submit

just got my app rejected.
Issue :

```
iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution
```

But i have set the Devices option in XCODE to be only on Iphone, does apple require me to run them on ipad as well?

Plus- i dont know if it's connected - they added this section :

```
PLA 3.3.12

We found that your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does not include ad functionality. This does not comply with the terms of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.


Specifically, section 3.3.12 of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement states:

"You and Your Applications (and any third party with whom you have contracted to serve advertising) may use the Advertising Identifier, and any information obtained through the use of the Advertising Identifier, only for the purpose of serving advertising. If a user resets the Advertising Identifier, then You agree not to combine, correlate, link or otherwise associate, either directly or indirectly, the prior Advertising Identifier and any derived information with the reset Advertising Identifier."

Note: iAd does not use the AdSupport framework, ASIdentifierManager, or the Advertising Identifier. Therefore they are not required for iAd implementations and should not be included in your app for iAd support.
```

2) Does the ads rejected me as well?  or they just added this with no connection to the rejection?

Comment: So, are they correct that you are using the Advertising Identifier for something other than advertising?

Comment: What else can i use the ads if not for ads?.. I just set banner in the bott of the page thats it

Comment: What is this ad identity? Is it possible that i added more code than i need to show and they are miss understood?

Comment: You forget to check Advertising Identifier in your binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple requires that apps run on all iOS platforms.  Accordingly I had to add constraints to my storyboard to adjust the location of subviews on each screen.  Because adding each constraint is tedious, I used Cirrious Fluent Layout which worked very well for me.  Below is the code I used on my screen that included a imageview.  This was the most complicated screen to "fix" because (apparently) the imagevies somehow changed all the screen sizes, being an iOS developer novice, I had no idea why this worked, only that it did.

First I needed to add the reference:

```
using Cirrious.FluentLayouts.Touch;
```

Code:

```
//This line is required to turn off all autosizing/positioning
View.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

// Get the screen dimensions and the middle of the screen 
// for button positioning

var barheight = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Bounds.Height; 
// Height of the navigation bar

var height = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height; 
var width = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
int middle = (int) UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width / 2;  
// We cast to int to truncate float, 
// int will convert implictly to float when used (Visual Studio).


var heightavailabletoimageviw = height -74 - 47 - 26 - 60; 
// 74 is the height of the banner, 47 is the height of the buttons and 
// 26 is the height of the title label plus a 5px gap  The rest of the 
// screen is available for use by the image view, 
// set heightavailabletoimageviw to this value
// Had to subtract 60 because the image view still overlapped 
// the buttons, no idea why.  Anyone?

// Had to add a constraint to the imageview because if I didn't
// it automatically scaled to the size of the image, not good.
ThePhoto.AddConstraints(
    ThePhoto.Width().EqualTo(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width),
    ThePhoto.Height().EqualTo(heightavailabletoimageviw) 
);

// Had to fix the size of the imagebutton otherwise the button size
// scaled to the size of the image
btnPhoto.AddConstraints(
    btnPhoto.Width().EqualTo(62f),
    btnPhoto.Height().EqualTo(47f)
);

// Now we add the constraints to the viewcontroller to finish up.
View.AddConstraints(

    // Can't cover the navigation bar (unless it isn't there, mine is), 
    // this value sets all other relative positions    
    Banner.AtTopOf(View, barheight), 
    Banner.AtRightOf(View, 0),
    Banner.AtLeftOf(View, 0),

    lblTitle.Below(Banner, 0),
    lblTitle.WithSameWidth(Banner),

    ThePhoto.Below(lblTitle, 5), 
    ThePhoto.WithSameWidth(lblTitle),

    // I have no idea why, but I had to use negative
    // values for the buttons to appear on the screen,
    // otherwise they were off screen.
    // If anyone could explain this, I would appreciate it.
    btnUpload.AtBottomOf(View),
    btnUpload.ToLeftOf(View,-60),

    // Same here, had to use negative values for button to
    // position correctly on the screen
    btnPhoto.AtBottomOf(View), 
    btnPhoto.ToLeftOf(View,-(middle + 31)),

   // Again, same thing.
   btnMainMenu.AtBottomOf(View),
   btnMainMenu.ToRightOf(View,-80)

);
```

This is how I solved my problem, I re-submitted the app and it now appears on the app store at: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/oml-photo-manager/id1212622377?mt=8.

Hope this helps someone ....

R/
Prescott ...

Comment: Tho it's old, I'm sure it'll help people. Thank you for your detailed answer Prescott !

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that when I posted.  It took me a while to figure out how to correct my app and there were no detailed answers anywhere so I figured I'd share.